# How to setup gracenote sample app in visual studio express 2012?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-express, gracenote

Getting this error while compiling gracenote sample app for windowsphone 8 with Visual Studio Express 2012:

```
Error   3   Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Gracenote.IGnMusicIdFileEvents'.   D:\Downloads\gn-mobile-winphone8-1.1.5.3105\sample\MainPage.xaml    GnMSDKSample
```

My step:
- install gn_winphone8_helper_sdk.vsix and gn_winphone8_sdk.vsix
- open sample/sample.sln file
- adding license.txt file
- change gnClientId_and gnClientIdTag_in App.xml.cs
- remove Gracenote obsolete references from project
- add Gracenote Windows Phone SDK v 1.1.5 reference
- add Gracenote Windows Phone SDK Helper v 1.1.5 reference
- compile -> error

What did i miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I'm not sure why, but after updating visualstudio, the error is gone.